# Error while trying to take multiple inputs in a switch inside a loop statement

Tags: c, switch-statement, do-while

So I am making a basic hotel/restaurant billing system and I am printing a menu and then taking inputs as choices while using a switch statement and the problem is that I am able to add one dish and select how many quantities of that dish you want and add tax and calculate total bill but I am unable to get a total bill for multiple dishes with multiple quantities. But I am able to get a total bill of multiple dishes having the same price and different quantities.

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    
    void main()
    {
        float food=0; // Total Food bill
        float p; // Quantity of food
        int ch; // Choice
        float vat,gst; // TAX
        float total; // Total bill
        int w; // Loop variable
    
    
        printf("\n ***Menu***\n Please choose items which you want to order from the list given below \n ---Tiffins--- \n 1. Plain Dosa = 50/- \n 2. Masala Dosa = 70/- \n 3. Onion Dosa = 80/- \n 4. Idli = 50/- \n 5. Uttapam = 90/- \n 6. Vada = 60/- \n 7. Upma = 65 /- \n 8. Pongal = 70/- \n 9. Puri = 70/- \n ");
        // Main Menu
        printf("\n Please enter your order: \n");
        scanf("%d",&ch); // Choice input
        do{ // Loop
            switch(ch)
        {
            case 1:
                printf("\n How many plates do you want to order: \n");
                scanf("%f",&p);
                food = food+50*p;
                printf("\nYour total as of right now: %.2f\n",food);
                break;
    
    
            case 2:
                printf("\n How many plates do you want to order: \n");
                scanf("%f",&p);
                food = food+70*p;
                printf("\nYour total as of right now: %.2f\n",food);
                break;
    
    
            case 3:
                printf("\n How many plates do you want to order: \n");
                scanf("%f",&p);
                food = food+80*p;
                printf("\nYour total as of right now: %.2f\n",food);
                break;
    
            case 4:
                printf("\n How many plates do you want to order: \n");
                scanf("%f",&p);
                food = food+50*p;
                printf("\nYour total as of right now: %.2f\n",food);
                break;
    
            case 5:
                printf("\n How many plates do you want to order: \n");
                scanf("%f",&p);
                food = food+90*p;
                printf("\nYour total as of right now: %.2f\n",food);
                break;
    
    
            case 6:
                printf("\n How many plates do you want to order: \n");
                scanf("%f",&p);
                food = food+60*p;
                printf("\nYour total as of right now: %.2f\n",food);
                break;
    
    
            case 7:
                printf("\n How many plates do you want to order: \n");
                scanf("%f",&p);
                food = food+65*p;
                printf("\nYour total as of right now: %.2f\n",food);
                break;
    
    
            case 8:
                printf("\n How many plates do you want to order: \n");
                scanf("%f",&p);
                food = food+70*p;
                printf("\nYour total as of right now: %.2f\n",food);
                break;
    
            case 9:
                printf("\n How many plates do you want to order: \n");
                scanf("%f",&p);
                food = food+70*p;
                printf("\nYour total as of right now: %.2f\n",food);
                break;
    
    
            default:
                printf("\nInvalid choice\n");
    
        }
    
        printf("\nPress 0 to go to billing\n");
        scanf("%d",&w);
    
    } while(w>0);
    
    vat = (7*food)/100;
    gst = (5*food)/100;
    total = food+vat+gst;
    printf("\n ---TOTAL BILL--- \n Food Total = %.2f \n Vat(7%%) = %.2f \n GST(5%%) = %.2f \n Total amount = %.2f \n",food,vat,gst,total);
    
    getch();
}
```

So yes it is a stupid basic beginner question but any help will be greatly appreciated. And yes I am Indian and yes those are Indian dishes.

Thank you!

Edit: Ok thank you its is fixed now all I had to do was move my choice input inside the loop. Thank you all for your help!

Comment: Side note: Do you really want the number of plates to be a floating point?

Comment: Side note: You do not really want a currency value in a float.

Comment: @SouravGhosh No I am sorry I forgot about that I will change it asap to a integer

Comment: @Yunnosch I wanted it to be float as down below when adding tax I get it in float so instead of converting it to float there I just madethe currency float.

Comment: Does some number plates have letters in them? Also start with a zero?

Comment: Keep currency as an integer (or long!). Work out the tax. Convert tax to integer (round up/down). Add that on. Keep currency as cents/pennies/...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're selecting the dish outside of the loop, so you're only asking for it once.  Move the code that does that to inside the loop at the top.  That way it asks each time.

```
do{ // Loop
    printf("\n ***Menu***\n Please choose items which you want to order from the list given below \n ---Tiffins--- \n 1. Plain Dosa = 50/- \n 2. Masala Dosa = 70/- \n 3. Onion Dosa = 80/- \n 4. Idli = 50/- \n 5. Uttapam = 90/- \n 6. Vada = 60/- \n 7. Upma = 65 /- \n 8. Pongal = 70/- \n 9. Puri = 70/- \n "); // Main Menu
    printf("\n Please enter your order: \n");
    scanf("%d",&ch); // Choice input
    ...
```

Comment: Perhaps `if (scanf(" %d", ^ch) == 1) { ....} else { ... eat input to clear buffer }`

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you read the dish input outside of the loop, that means that after you select the first dish, you won't be able to choose another one:

```
printf("\n Please enter your order: \n");
scanf("%d",&ch); // Choice input
do{ // Loop
switch(ch)
```

If you, instead, put your it like this:

```
do{ // Loop
printf("\n Please enter your order: \n");
scanf("%d",&ch); // Choice input
switch(ch)
```

The user will be able to choose diferent dishes.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you write

```
printf("\nPress 0 to go to billing\n");
scanf("%d",&w);

}while(w>0);
```

however, in the check you're checking for a value greater than 0. You should change that to

```
}while (w ==0);
```

That said, if you really want the menu to be repeated, you need to move the print and user input for menu inside the `do...while` loop.

Comment: I wrote w>0 as I want the user the ability to add another dish after already selecting a dish and selecting how much quantity of that dish so what happens is until the user presses 0 they are on the menu and can select as many dishes as their choosing but as I am a beginner noob just let me know is there a better way to do it than this.